# Wait until forEach fetch data from db

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to implement a forEach to fetch data from a mongo database and push each data to an array. I need to console log that array after all data is pushed. I tried with a promises but couldn't get desired result. Here's what I've got

```
count=[];
array.forEach((data)=>{
    userDetailsModel.find({UpdateStatusDate:data}).countDocuments()
    .exec((err,data)=>{count.push(data)}) 
})
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your function has `async` keyword infront of it and you should be good to go

```
let count = await Promise.all(
  array.map(data =>
    userDetailsModel
      .find({ UpdateStatusDate: data })
      .countDocuments()
      .exec()
  )
);
consle.log(count);
```

Comment: Thank You. I tried this but it hits error saying await is valid only in async function

Comment: @JerinJoseph yes. and i said "make sure your function has `async` keyword infront of it` did you added it?

Comment: @JerinJoseph you can use my version as it does not require the function to be `async`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the point of the promise pattern applied to an array of promises.

`Exec` will return a promise that will resolve only for one element of the data array.
Thus you will have a promise for each data in your array and your code must wait for all promises to resolve. Keep in mind this will result in one Mongo query per data in your array.

Best way to do so is to map your data array to an array of promises and use `Promise.all` to wait for all of them to resolve:

```
// get an array of promises for each data to query:
let promises = array.map(data => { 
    return userDetailsModel
        .find({UpdateStatusDate:data})
        .countDocuments()
        .exec(); 

});
    
// when all the promises fulfill 
Promise.all(promises).then(counts => {
    console.log(counts);
    // for each counts log the result:
    counts.forEach(result => { console.log(result); });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Promise/all) method to wait after all promises

```
let count = [];
const promiseArray = array.map((data) => (
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    userDetailsModel.find({ UpdateStatusDate: data })
      .countDocuments()
      .exec((err, data) => { resolve(data) })
  })
))
Promise.all(promiseArray).then((values) => {
  count = values;
  console.log(count);
});
```